# Which is better GCM or Sockets for chat application?

Tags: android, socket.io, google-cloud-messaging, chat

I'm new to android and heard that for chat application we can use either of the two approach, Socket or Gcm, but I'm confused that which one is better for future prospective. Can anyone drag me out of this confusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not suggest to make chat application with GCM because it will slow down the speed of chatting. You can implement your chat using Quickblox apis. Its free, comes with good features, reliable and easy to implement. Here is the example for a chat application http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample

Also you can use ejabberd  https://www.ejabberd.im/ on your server and Smack  https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack in your android client to connect with ejabberd server. If you are using ubuntu server then here is an excellent guide to install ejabberd https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ejabberd-xmpp-server-on-ubuntu